# AsyncTask causes reload problems (doubled items, wrong data, etc.), but running on UI is too slow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I make use of an RV. This is it's reload adapter:

```
    private async void SetContent(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)        {
        await SetContentAsync(vh, position);
    }

    private async Task SetContentAsync(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)
    {
        string SongName = "";
        string ArtistName = "";
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        byte[] data = null;
        RequestOptions requestOptions = null;

        try
        {
           reader.SetDataSource(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);
        }
        catch
        {
            Toast.MakeText(ctx, "ERROR 77s9", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }


       // await Task.Run(() => // cause problems with the reload
       // {
            SongName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
            ArtistName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist);

            data = reader.GetEmbeddedPicture();

            if (data != null)
            {
                 try
                 {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);

                    requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                    requestOptions.InvokeDiskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.None);
                   // requestOptions.SkipMemoryCache(true);
                    requestOptions.CircleCrop();
                    requestOptions.CenterInside();
                    requestOptions.FitCenter();
                    requestOptions.OptionalCircleCrop();


                    ConvertBitmapToBackground(bitmap, vh, data); // Set As Backgorund, blurry and black ( just sets the variable)
                 }
                 catch
                 {
                     Toast.MakeText(ctx, "ERROR 034c", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                 }
    }

        //});



        ((Activity)ctx).RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            vh.SongName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            vh.AristName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            vh.SongName.Text = SongName;
            vh.AristName.Text = ArtistName;

             try
             {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    Glide
                         .With(ctx)
                         .Load(data)
                         .Apply(requestOptions)
                         .Into(vh.CoverArt);


                }
                else // because recycler items inherit their shit and if it is altered it just shows views were there shouldnt be any ... 
                {
                    vh.CoverArt.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_musicalnote);
                    vh.dr = null;
                }
             }
             catch {
                Toast.MakeText(ctx, "ERROR 034c", ToastLength.Short).Show();
             }

        });


    }
```

As you can see, the part where the data is being decoded used to be in an async method to not stuck up the UI thread. However, this caused issues while loading. Under heavy work, items had the wrong info, items doubled, sometimes even trippeled. The problem was solved by removing the async task and doing it all synchronous. However, this makes the whole app a lot laggier.

How do I use asnyc task in a RV correctly, without messing up the items?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
private async void SetContent(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)
{
  await SetContentAsync(vh, position);
}
```

One of the [problems with `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) is that the calling code has no idea when that method has completed. As far as your RV knows, it asked your code to set the content, and the code returned, so it figures it has whatever content it's going to get.

This is a fundamental problem with every UI framework: when the computer/device needs to show something, it needs to show it *now*. The data to display *must* be available synchronously.

So, how do we reconcile this with the necessity of loading that data from I/O, along with the notion that I/O should be asynchronous?

One common pattern is to (synchronously) load placeholder data. A "loading..." message or spinner or whatever. The same code also *starts* loading the real data asynchronously. When that data arrives (i.e., the I/O completes), then the UI is *updated* (synchronously) to display the real data.

You may find my [article on asynchronous data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) useful. It takes the Placeholder Data pattern and applies it to data-binding UI frameworks (WPF, Xamarin, etc). I think you're using the lower-level Android UI APIs, so the code won't be directly relevant, but you should be able to do something similar. The resulting code will be more verbose than using data binding, but the same concepts and pattern should apply.